# Create an accordion with toogle tabing fading effect

Tags: jquery, tabs, accordion, fade, slidetoggle

I´d like to make an accordion with toggle and fade-effect.

Here my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5Y7p/2/)

and two screens:

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

So, onclick on "Panel 1" or "Panel 2" the content should toogle down and up, too.

When I´ve choose one of theme and I click on the other panel, than the content should move
by fadingIn and not toggle.

On screen 2) is a "close-button", this should close everytime all panel-contents and goes back to
screen 1).

English isn´t my first language.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the effect you're going for: http://jsfiddle.net/n5Y7p/3/ ?
Quick and dirty, to get you started

Edit: My apologies. I've just realized that you wanted to crossfade the content.

Comment: isotrope - WOW pretty cool that´s quick and dirty for you? I updated the fiddle: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n5Y7p/4/). I added a close link. Now I have 2 issues: first, if panel 1 and 2 are slidedown they can´t slideUp by clicking on itself, too. second, can I crossfading both contents, when they´re slidedown - at the moment they were siliding. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's the thing.. quick and dirty, because I would've reworked the content a bit so that I can apply the scripting to an element, read parts of it's attributes and classes to know which button affects which panel automatically. Currently, you'll have to set up yet another bunch of code if you add a third one, and a fourth one, ....

Comment: I updated it a bit for you: http://jsfiddle.net/n5Y7p/5/   No need to put more than one $(document).ready();   As for the crossfading, I'd rework how the content is presented. I would go with placing them both one in front of the other and then fade one in while you fade the other one out

Comment: We posted at the same time. So crossfading is done. Just one thing, the last [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/n5Y7p/9) looks very good and the cossfading works. When panel 1 or 2 is active/shown, I can´t slideUp the active panel by clicking the own panel-button, just with the "close x" button.

Comment: @ogni I think that 10 is going to be the magic number -> http://jsfiddle.net/n5Y7p/10/  Thanks for accepting my answer above. I'll edit it with this one if it's the exact result you were going for. Cheers, iso.

Comment: man you´re so great! yeah, "10" is awesome - the exact result I try to explain. you´re welcome. Hope to see you here next time. Bye ogni

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8881/discussion-between-ogni-and-isotrope)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you take a look at:  http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

The implementation is fairly simple and easily customized.